# How to parse JSON response prepended with {} && in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

JMeter provided a post processor JSON extractor to extract JSON element in a response

However, my test site is returning JSON with {}&& in the beginning of the JSON string that makes JMeter JSON extractor to fail.

How do I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove first 4 symbols from the response and replace the response with the "sanitized" value.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the JSON with `{}&&` characters in the beginning
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def oldResponse = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   def newResponse = oldResponse.drop(4)
   prev.setResponseData(newResponse, 'UTF-8')
   ```
3. Make sure to put your JSON Extractor **after** the JSR223 PostProcessor

Test plan structure:

[image]

In the above code snippet `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for all available functions description and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Answer (score -1):

There could be number of solutions to this.

Solution 1
Use the [JMeter Custom Function StrReplace](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) to remove the prefix and assign the result to a variable.

Use JSON Extractor to evaluate the variable
[image]

Solution 2
Use JSR223 Post Processor to extract the values

Comment: I created JSR223 PostProcessor and could see the string get into the vars. I was unable to print it from a JSR233 Assertion script, for example log.info ("aa:"+vars.get("aa")); In addition , if I need the variable to be thread local, what can I do?